# Предпросмотр фотографии

Tags: android

Пишу приложения для хранение фотографий и отсыла их на сервер с помощью ZIP.
Но мне захотелось слегка изменить интерфейс "предпросмотра фотографии" где можно нажать крестик или галочку, хотелось бы изменить их на более заметные кнопки.

Еще хотелось бы узнать как вовсе убрать этот предпросмотр?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Запускаю фото активити так

```
 private void saveImage(String folder) throws IOException {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        File photofile=createImageFile(folder);
        photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "app.service.photoapp.fileprovider", photofile);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICTURE_REQUEST);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Организовал свою "камеру" с помощью `hardware.camera`

Answer (score 0):

Очевидно, что затея пустая. Вы никак не измените чужое приложение. Создайте свой элемент для выбора фотографий с диска, очень даже посильная задача